# iOS not working scroll overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have problems with the scroll on iOS, using overflow: hidden in coupled with webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

The div does not flow, but if I try to delete webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; returns to scrorre but not smoothly. The problem is if I set my webapp like Add to Home. This is the class that I use for the container div:

```
.content {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: auto;
background-color: #ecf0f1;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

While this for the body tag

```
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
color: #000;
background: #000;
overflow: hidden;
```

Ps. The problem manifests itself only in portrait and in landscape work correctly

Do you have any advice?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Would be useful to have a jsFiddle or similar demonstrating the problem.